# Simple SVN commands

Tags: svn, addition

Seemingly lame question, but I've been through all the docs and tutorials and am unable to figure out exactly what I want.

My repo is 
    https://sourcerepo.something/mystuff

My working folder is
    /var/www

I copy new files into
    /var/www  (that are not under source control since they are new)

I revise some files in
    /var/www  (that are already under source control)

What command would I use to add new and updated files?
What command would I use to subsequently commit?

The command

```
svn add /var/www/
```

will add all files, even the unchanged files that are already under source control.  I get a thousand messages warning that the files are "already under source control"

What commandline would I use to just add new and updated files?

Thanks so much.

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend:

```
$ svn status
```

Will give you status of all files, including those that need to be added.

```
$ svn add /var/www/only/new/files
```

And finally:

```
$ svn commit
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use

`svn add newfilename`

Later when you next commit, they will be added to the repository. If you do this a lot it might be a good idea to make a shell alias or script that does the copy and svn add for you.

Comment: I think the point was to try to add those files without having to list them one by one on the command line.

Answer (score 0):

Use `svn --force` to force it to do this.  Note that you don't `add` modified files, you simply `commit` the changes.

Be careful, though.  Doing a blanket `add` is a good way to end up with all sorts of crud in your SVN repository.

Comment: Note that "svn add --force" has an extra effect: if you have directories under (in this case) /var/www that are already version-controlled, but that contain files that haven't been added, it will add them. (Normally "svn add" doesn't recurse into such directories.)

Answer (score 0):

You can make "svn add" shut up by passing the "-q" or "--quiet" flag. As well as not complaining about unchanged files, it will then also not tell you about the ones it *is* adding, but you can do "svn status" to see what it's done.

No need to add updated files -- "add" means to make files version-controlled *that weren't before*. "svn commit" will automatically commit the changes you've made to already-version-controlled files.

Comment: `-q` simply turns off messages; it doesn't change the behaviour of `add`.

Answer (score 0):

I have the perfect little gem for you.

```
svn status | grep "^?" | awk '{print $2}' | xargs svn add
```

This basically says do "svn status" then get all the NEW fils marked as "?" bunch them together and then do an "svn add" on the list.

After that you just need to do your commit.